# How to use tf.data.Dataset.ignore_errors to ignore errors in a Tensorflow Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

When loading images from a directory in Tensorflow, you use something like:

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "S:\\Images",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(128,128),
    label_mode=None,
    validation_split=0.20, #Reserve 20% of images for validation
    subset='training',     #If we specify a validation_split, we *must* specify subset
    seed=619               #If using validation_split we *must* specify a seed to ensure there is no overlap between training and validation data
)
```

But of course some of the images (`.jpg`, `.png`, `.gif`, `.bmp`) will be invalid. So we want to ignore those errors; just skip them (and **ideally** log the filenames so they can be repaired, removed, or deleted).

There have been some ideas along the way of how to ignore invalid images:

### Method 1: `tf.contrib.data.ignore_errors` (Tensorflow 1.x only)

> **Warning:** The tf.contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0.

Sample usage:

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.ignore_errors())
```

The only down-side of this method is that [it was only available in Tensorflow 1](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/ignore_errors). Trying to use it today simply won't work, as the `tf.contib` namespace no longer exists. That led to a built-in method:

### Method 2: [`tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors(log_warning=False)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/ignore_errors) (deprecated)

From the documentation:

> Creates a Dataset from another Dataset and silently ignores any errors. (deprecated)
>
> **Deprecated:** THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use [`tf.data.Dataset.ignore_errors`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#ignore_errors) instead.

Sample usage:

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors(log_warning=True))
```

And this method works. It works great. And it has the advantage of working.

But it's apparently deprecated, and they documentation says we should use method 3:

### Method 3 - [`tf.data.Dataset.ignore_errors(log_warning=False, name=None)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#ignore_errors)

> Drops elements that cause errors.

Sample usage:

```
dataset = dataset.ignore_errors(log_warning=True, name="Loading images from directory")
```

### Except it doesn't work

The `dataset.ignore_errors` attribute doesn't work, and gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'ignore_errors'

Which means:

- the thing that works is deprecated
- they tell us to use this other thing instead
- and *"provide the instructions for updating"*
- but the other thing doesn't work

So we ask Stackoverflow:

> How do i use `tf.data.Dataset.ignore_errors` to ignore errors?

## Bonus Reading

- [TensorFlow Dataset `.map` - Is it possible to ignore errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966969/tensorflow-dataset-map-is-it-possible-to-ignore-errors)
- [TensorFlow: How to skip broken data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325648/tensorflow-how-to-skip-broken-data)

### Untested Workaround

Not only is it not what i was asking, but people are not allowed to read this:

> It looks like the `tf.data.Dataset.ignore_errors()` method is not
> available in the `BatchDataset` object, which is what you are using in
> your code. You can try using `tf.data.Dataset.filter()` to filter out
> elements that cause errors when loading the images. You can use a
> try-except block inside the lambda function passed to `filter()` to
> catch the errors and return False for elements that cause errors,
> which will filter them out. Here's an example of how you can use
> `filter()` to achieve this:
>
> ```
> def filter_fn(x):   
>   try:
>     # Load the image and do some processing
>     # Return True if the image is valid, False otherwise
>     return True   
>   except:
>     return False
>
> dataset = dataset.filter(filter_fn)
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use the `tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors()`
> method, which is currently available in TensorFlow 2.x. This method
> will silently ignore any errors that occur while processing the
> elements of the dataset. However, keep in mind that this method is
> experimental and may be removed or changed in a future version.

Comment: I guess `tf.data.Dataset.ignore_errors()` is introduced in TF 2.11

Answer (score -1):

[`tf.data.Dataset.ignore_errors`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#ignore_errors) was introduced in TensorFlow 2.11. You can use [`tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/ignore_errors) for older versions like so:

```
dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
```